# Is there a VB script that permanently changes the language in Outlook 2016?

Tags: microsoft-outlook, microsoft-outlook-2016

I would like to change Outlook 2016 default language, however it continues to revert back to en-us from en-gb. I have tried changing the language from system locale, removed en-us, did the config through Outlook to set en-gb as default and uncheck the "Detect language automatically" from Proofing language however when I close the Outlook application and re-open, it reverts back to en-us. Is there a VBscript I can use to make the changes set permanently?

Comment: Have you tried changing the language then removing en-us?

Comment: Yes, it does nothing :(